# Can't find a »Back to search results« link on contact pages

Tags: search, ui

When visiting a contact from the results list of a civicrm search, it's possible to navigate forward and backwards through the results set.

Wouldn't it be good to add back-to-list-button which targets the search results list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree.

Once good way to do this would be to add a breadcrumb link here:
[image]

It was fairly simple so I just created a pull-request to add this to the upcoming 4.7 release.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7555

Comment: Wow, this is cool!
In my understanding the breadcrumbs are hierarchically and it kind of breaks the hierarchy. 
Don't you think it would better fit between those previous and next buttons?
But it's super-helpful anyway, thanks!